# Mapping a list to a different type

Tags: c++, list, dictionary, templates, lambda

I'm trying to make a `List` class, mainly because there are some methods that aren't present for vectors that I'd like to implement myself. One of these is a `map()` function where you can pass in a lambda as a parameter and the method returns a new `List` in which each of the values in the old list was passed to the function.

The problem I'm having is with getting the method to deal with returning a `List` featuring a different type. For example:

```cpp
List<Option<int>> y;
y.append(option(1));
y.append(option(2));
y.append(option(3)); 
//y is [Option(1), Option(2), Option(3)]

List<int> z = y.map([](Option<int> o) {return o.get();});

//z should be [1,2,3]
```

Where the `map()` function, in it's current state, is defined as:

```cpp
template<typename S>
List<S> map(S (* function)(T)) {
    List<S> output;     
    for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
        output.append(function((*this)[i]));
    }
    return output;
}
```

The problem is that the above doesn't seem to allow me to pass in a lambda, only a previously defined function, which defeats the purpose of convenience for the method. The only way I can get it to accept a lambda is by defining the function as:

```cpp
template<typename S, typename R>
List<S> map(R function) {
    List<S> output;  
    for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
        output.append(function((*this)[i]));
    }
    return output;
}
```

But this results in a different problem, where it says:

> no instance of function template 'List<T>::map[with T=Option<int>]' matches the argument list

Is there a particular workaround for this, or will I have to declare functions for each time I call the `map()` function?

Comment: C++-idiomatic map is called `std::transform`, btw.

Comment: You should look into the `auto` return type and into the `type_traits` library, particularly `std::invoke_result`

Comment: S is just for the method. My intention was to clarify that the List type may differ from that of the list calling the method. I'm still getting used to C++ (I'm more used to Scala) so that's where my mentality was. Also, looking at std::transform (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) it appears that it directly mutates the value being called. I'm aiming to stick to a functional paragdim, so the method is meant to return a new list all together, rather than alter the list itself.

Comment: @GLGuy `std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), std::back_inserter(output), function)` is a thing. There's also [`transform_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/transform_view), new in C++20, which is very different from the old C++ way of doing things but also should be more familiar to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `decltype`. In your definition, you want to determine the type of the `output` list return value with what would be returned from the function. So you can do something like this:

```
template<typename R>
auto map(R function) {
    List<std::decay_t<decltype(function(operator[](0)))>> output;
    for(int i = 0; i < size(); i++) output.append(function(operator[](i)));
    return output;
}
```

The type of the list elements is whatever `function` returns when called on the elements of `this`. The `std::decay_t` turns types you can't store (references, cv-qualified types, arrays, etc) into those you can (resp. non-references, none-qualified types, pointers, etc.).

A slightly more powerful result can be achieved with `std::invoke_result`, which lets you replace the function call with `std::invoke`:

```
template<typename T>
struct List {          // Your list class, we need the T
    template<typename R>
    auto map(R function) {
        List<std::decay_t<std::invoke_result_t<R, T&>>> output; // assuming that accesses give references
        for(int i = 0; i < size(); i++) output.append(std::invoke(function, operator[](i)));
        return output;
    }
};
```

The result is that now you can also `map` things like pointers to members over your list.

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tLgHZSW9ABk8tTADljAI0zEQkgKykADqgWE6rR6hibmvv6BdLb2Tkau7l6KypiqQQwEzMQEIcamnBZKKmp0GVkEMY4ubh7eCpnZuWEFig0VdlXxNV4AlIqoBsTIHADkUgDMdsiGWADU4uM6VAa0aXRsC9jiAAwAghNTM5jziwQAnj6YAPoExMyECps7%2B5KTq0cnOgBuqUTET3tngRMEYfMJgQsdOdLrRmEZjgAVAG7abMBQKWa2erzMyyPazAmzeroEAgH6qEiQpHjbCzdDMTILPG7HwGZysPDIEDPQmzAwBUREvAAL2u0OOCwAIrNxbD4USCCSyb9KYtqdhSQFRTcLpgmTzCVqxbqhaKID1ZmhaNjaKhMAAPYY%2BAg45m83nETAEQa0OkM5gAOiN5v1%2BMJ4jMkoNBK%2BqDw6FmzB8MPQEARs3tFojbvdBPpmQDrIUCCuzmYyAA1hBiaSjKgfhBMz1Q7teRGo2GCempAA2VCXO5/cSeWSeSXVkXGy6zPAW20Op0u7PR92e73EX355jD6R4YdR8Y5gntlfpq3Y3v9twMykj/cT7XimcW88u%2BeOzDO10rj1en1%2BxkRz3McWzbSMV2BUFwT1U5dTlY4ADFkV5AB6FCZ19CQZDkThOFITE8HqSFZThY4axALAWDOSFKNYcVqAgK9B1vUdx22HoOM2UlxWQwk0MTbRE1YBRUBXfjmAMIhZiMJNOAgBDZioC0AFpNgIojYJhUiFSVSjmGoxZaPoqhGIHG9/jvMcIHYziaW43U1OXTtE0k1BpNk%2BTFKzXEf0JLECEhci9LOG4aNSOjdQYpjzJ3e8bObGk1IGAhWQCw9fIJGhiAfKdjjwE5pW2JkZ0%2BU1MBDQ8ZzkOQLWS1KAyTFMorModLPHWdbKPVc/w3WY6sk0Dw3A5z%2BLoVgzkTL57mEdljiw2QZAKPraAgkEwQZGCoTg7SkMS5yJKkmSfEkTylO/ZzeX8wLFVJYLQsWci7FjCtrk9BQDDo%2B6dAQ/CkUkHsnkSmk%2Bsk1LBtzLKcp1ad8qlWYisq2HFjKirpCq7CZFq0HJIa5MrGrG6QCe1AXuofDota1iIA6hKut/ddfX6tKupPQFwPSwFAVeQ4DDmSF1HqT04WRA53l5iVFkkvAOXOEW9jsF0ZLsc1ztbQl%2BTsYBZj8BWCp00kfHuf5FgV/CFcBrqrsWHX6DUm2CEeDm1YJe2FFxprs22fCisjWmV1d938ezPDZk4ds/ecgPGqD3FeFD8Pwe1uN6Dd6PtAgbM48kBOnd5KO8fTzP8PGHOuoOtz8HqK4FAARwxOGA6OuTYqs%2B35n%2B%2B3vLRtd/3tgMqDwYhsQAKiThX%2B8Hi8ZDH%2Bgg1SOgE1HvulCtdBitLldy9mM56/GaVG6TE7e3tzV5%2B0CPncUkgICMyLXZ6TVJ2hvK9YRtGkZ0GeHaDSdUfRhbpAWnImgSSnxITt0kJXAKnhsCSBABAsByMoHVzrjuYC0pITgKkJIbe8DsGIM/jvNB%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%3D%3D)

Comment: @HTNW, thank you for the edit, but this level of answer re-write, you should really just make your own answer.

Comment: I didn't really add anything material you didn't already say (except for the `std::invoke` thing), so I didn't feel comfortable doing that. Hope that's OK.

Comment: @HTNW, not a problem for me, it is a good edit. Its just you put so much effort into mine that could have just been a better answer for you.

Comment: Got it to work using the decltype. Thanks for the help!